# Update SQL database PHP

Tags: php, sql

I have a form that posts variables back from a drop down list in php.  I then need to take those values and update my database values for each "TeamName".  I am using the following code but nothing is updating.

```
$g1 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['g1']);

$conn = mysql_connect("****.com","****","*****") or die("Connection to MYSQL");
mysql_select_db("****_teamlist", $conn) or die("Connection to MYSQL database failed");
$sSQL = "UPDATE Sheet1 Set g1='$g1' WHERE TeamName = 'TeamName' ";
$result = mysql_query($sSQL, $conn) or die(mysql_error());
```

Where is my error?  I am stuck.

Comment: what is WHERE TeamName = 'TeamName' for ?

Comment: `mysql_real_escape_string` needs a valid connection.

Comment: no mysql_real_escape_string does not need a valid connection mysqli_real_escape_string() needs a valid connection.

Comment: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty: `A MySQL connection is required before using mysql_real_escape_string() otherwise an error of level E_WARNING is generated, and FALSE is returned. [...]` Manual...

Comment: TeamName is a column in the table--each teamname will have a g1

Comment: U should use `$g1 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['g1']);
` after `$conn = mysql_connect("****.com","****","*****") or die("Connection to MYSQL");`

Comment: and please write the error message or explain where is UR problem